# How to access derived objects properties when they are stored in a Parent typed collection?

Tags: c#, inheritance, dictionary, casting, unity-game-engine

I works on a RPG and I am stuck on how to make a global list of all items of the world. I works with Unity3D.

My items could be weapons, currency, macscots and dozen of subderived class.

So I have a base Class Item (simplified code)

```
public class Item{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Vector2 GeoCoord{get;set;}
    public int OwnerId{get;set;}
    public string State{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public Type Type{get;set;}
}
```

and sub classes

```
public class WeaponModel: Item {

    public Type CloseTargetBehavior{get;set;}
    public Type DistantTargetBehavior{get;set;}
    ...
}

public class MascotModel: Item {

    public MascotCategory Category {get; set;}
    ...
}


public class ConsumableModel: Item {

    public float Price {get; set;}
    ...    
}
```

For saving purpose and others reasons, I would like to store all the instances of those derived class in a dictionary (or anything else). But I read it is not recommended to store multi typed objects in a collection because you can only access their common properties (here Item's class properties).

So what is the best way to have a global list of all sort of objects and still get access to their properties?

**EDIT 1 : Added some details on usage**

My first use for this collection is to use it as a description  for some "factories":

1)When the game starts, I deserialize a JSON files which build this unique collection. I use http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/Json-NET-for-Unity-Developers
I use a settings.TypeNameHandling   = TypeNameHandling.All; parameter to keep all class/subclasses description.

2)Different concrete GameObject, which could be assimilated as a View element, are made to use in 2Dmap, 3Dworld, inventory... but each representation refers to the subclass instance (WeaponModel or MascotModel or...). Eg : a clic on an item on the map, or in the 3D view will both change the state of the Model.

I thought about "if(typeOf(WeaponModel)) else if..."
But this is the start point of my confusion. I am looking a more generic way to do this because I don't know how many subclass I will have.

I tried some dynamic casting, but I read it is not possible in C#.
This is my try :

```
Type type = Items[key].GetType();
Debug.Log(type()); //WeaponModel but I have no access to the method/property

Item item = (type) Items[key]; // Cast don't work
Debug.Log(item.CloseTargetBehavior) // Still no access to subclass property

Item item = (WeaponModel) Items[key]; // Cast works because it is a declarative type
Debug.Log(item.CloseTargetBehavior) // I have ccess to subclass property
```

Comment: Do you want a list or a dictionary? What are you going to use this global list/dictionary for? Your objects could always be in more than one collection.. Or you could have "virtual" collections like `public IEnumerable<Weapon> Weapons { get { return AllItems.OfType<Weapon>(); } }`

Comment: How will you want to access them in the future? As each object is separate and has separate methods/properties on it, why do you wish to store all the objects in the same collection and not in separate collections anyway?
If you want to just keep a list, then some form of `IEnumerable<Item>` would be okay, and then use the `OfType` property as Blorgbeard mentions, or, for an individual item, you can check, eg `if(Item item is MascotModel) { } else if(Item item is ConsumableModel) { }` etc...

Comment: @Blorgbeard I have not stopped my choice on any collection type or number of dimensions. I am not very comfortable with virtual, generic and <T> things yet. Have you got any noob exemple/ressource somewhere ?

Comment: @DavidE I edited the question for you :)

Comment: I change the title from "dictionary" to "collection"

Comment: Mm okay, in your example at the bottom, you try to do `item.CloseTargetBehaviour`.. Surely this only makes sense for a weapon? Or at least for a certain subset of items? In which case, you could have, Eg, `DistanceDependentItem : Item`, and then you can, Eg, filter your list where you require access to all items which you can use `CloseTargetBehavior` on at that time. Alternatively you could use interfaces which might be even easier if some items fall into multiple classes...

Comment: If I understand, this could retrieve all the WeaponModel ? The fact is I manage to do this right now by simply checking the Item Type. (I improved my example for you to see).
But even if is is a WeaponModel I still have no access to its property/method... unless I recast is declaratively again as a WeaponModel.
I hope I have not misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Indeed. Okay, I was hoping that through your usage we might be able to restructure your classes / interfaces etc to make things more easily extensible, but if not, I'd suggest Ascendion's answer (with his edit) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the real issue here is the serializer/deserializer used to store the data offline. Whatever choice is made, the deserializer has to be Type aware so it recreates objects of the correct type when the save data is imported. The .Net XML and Binary serializers both store detailed type information and deserialize to the correct types.

If your primary container (the root object that you serialize/deserialize) for saving all the data had a List<> for each derived type that you wanted to store, you would get typed access to the stored data without jumping through a lot of hoops. I don't see the point of using a dictionary at all since you store item and owner IDs in the Item base class and you can scan the lists after deserializing to reattach the items to their associated owners.

```
The only thing you MIGHT want a dictionary for is to create an ItemContainer 
object with a common/generic method for adding items like: 

Container.AddItem<WeaponModel>(WeaponModel item); 

or accessing the lists based on the derived type 

Container.GetList<WeaponModel>()
Container.GetItemByID<WeaponModel>(int id)

so that you don't have to explicitly create a container class with all the typed lists.. 

simply adding a derived object using these methods would create a list of the 
derived type and add/remove/access data from it in a transparent manner, 
and it would still work correctly with the serializer/deserializer.
```

**EDIT: as requested a quick example of a generic technique to store data of any type derived from Item that is accessible in strongly typed fashion:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Vector2 GeoCoord { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Type Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemContainer
    {
        private Dictionary<Type, object> items;

        public ItemContainer()
        {
            items = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        }

        public T Get<T>(int id) where T: Item
        {
            var t = typeof(T);
            if (!items.ContainsKey(t)) return null;
            var dict = items[t] as Dictionary<int, T>;
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(id)) return null;
            return (T)dict[id];
        }

        public void Set<T>(T item) where T: Item
        {
            var t = typeof(T);
            if (!items.ContainsKey(t))
            {
                items[t] = new Dictionary<int, T>();
            }
            var dict = items[t] as Dictionary<int, T>;
            dict[item.Id] = item;
        }

        public Dictionary<int, T> GetAll<T>() where T : Item
        {
            var t = typeof(T);
            if (!items.ContainsKey(t)) return null;
            return items[t] as Dictionary<int, T>;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to detail this.
Indeed I use a JSON.Net portage http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/Json-NET-for-Unity-Developers

And I set a parameter 

settings.TypeNameHandling  = TypeNameHandling.All;

To handle all the subtype.

Comment: In response to your edit: If you use a generic typed getter against a combined list of derrived type objects, you can set things up to where if you as for Get&lt;WeaponModel%>(int id) it will return null if that ID is not a WeaponModel, and a simple Get(int id) will return the base Item type, then you can test the type "if (item is WeaponModel) etc"... Since you aren't familiar with generic methods I'll throw up another answer with an example container class like I just suggested since it won't fit in a comment

Comment: I just edited my answer with the sample code. Note the use of generic constraints so the class only works with objects derived from the Item type, yet it still stores and returns strongly typed objects.

Comment: Should this be `private Dictionary<System.Type, Dictionary<int, Item>> items`? And maybe a `GetAll<T>` function might also be nice?
But anyway, great answer :)

Comment: I was just getting some bare minimums up there to show you how to do generic methods.. the type of backing store and methods you provide to manipulate it are up to you :)

Comment: I left out the using declarations... you need System and System.Collections.Generic... for your GetAll method there may be some use to going with a partly untyped backing store (Dictionary&letint, object&gt;) so you can store strongly typed int/item dictionaries to be returned by the GetAll&lttype&gt method... that would require a bit more casting internally, but keep everything strongly typed on the exposed methods

Comment: OK -- modified code with the changes from my last comment and to have a simple GetAll method... a little bit cleaner than looping through all the items and copying them to a new dictionary

Comment: Great ! I begin to see what generic is for ! I try to implement it right now.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Ascendion I test your code and it works well.
I understand that the dynamic typing is not convenient due to its overheads.
So at that point, and sorry if it is another noob consideration, but what are the advantages of your code compared to Daniel one ?

Comment: My setup does not require selecting/filtering against a combined list to get all items of a specific type, and if you need lists for different types, you have to run that code over and over. My take is that you will typically be doing things with specific derived types and not caring about other derived types in that section of code. If you DID need a reason to scan every item of every derived type as Item types, it would be easy enough to create an IEnumerator method that yields Item objects from all the dictionaries combined, but in such a way that temporary lists/dicts are not needed.

Comment: Something like IEnumerator<Item> GetItems() { foreach (var t in items.values) { foreach (var i in t.values) yeild i; } } } -- Thus you don't HAVE to store everything as a single list to get a return value that LOOKS like a single list :)

Comment: OK I am impressed. Seems very logic once explained, and I thank you twice for the code and for explanations. And thx you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking for a single global list of all items, so this will handle exactly that scenario.

To store the items:

```
public static List<Item> GlobalItems = new List<Item>();
```

In order to get access to the properties of a derived type, you will have to cast the Item to it's derived type.

To determine it's current type, use:

```
var itemType = item.GetType();
```

To use an item as it's derived type:

```
Item item = GlobalItems[0];
DerivedItem derivedItem = item as DerivedItem;
if(derivedItem == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item is not a DerivedItem");
}
```

To get all items from the list which are a certain type:

```
var derivedItems = GlobalItems.Where(item => item.GetType() == typeof(DerivedItem)).Select(item => (DerivedItem)item);
```

Comment: Thx you @Daniel, I am at the same poing as you indeed. But I am confusing about futur maintainability.
What about 20+ more subclass ? Do you think the code would be maintainable withour rewrite hundred lines of codes ?
Now the question is : Is there a way to do this with a dynamic casting way ? (look at the end of my edited question).

Comment: I think this would also be reasonably maintainable (and could be improved with interfaces or subclasses for future-similar-items), but -no- it is very hard to do it the dynamic casting way- and anyway, why would you want to? Reflection adds in extra overheads and slows down code... Any code you run (say) on a weapon, you'll know is a weapon, and so can cast to it - or you can store it separately as some sort of weapon enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a possibility to Ascendion's answer (who gets all the credit for writing it up), you could also add the method:

```
    public Dictionary<int, T> GetAll<T>() where T: Item
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        if (!items.ContainsKey(t)) return null;
        var derivedItemDict = new Dictionary<int,T>();
        foreach(var item in items[t]) {
            derivedItemDict.Add(item.Key, (T)item.Value);
        }
        return derivedItemDict;
    }
```

And then you could, eg, do:

```
Items.GetAll<Weapon>();
```

to return a `Dictionary<int, Weapon>` for you.. Ie it would return you the strongly-typed dictionary I believe you seek. But note that if you use this a lot, the result of this should really be saved separately between changes so you don't have to repetitively do all these casts.